# How can I split a list into a list of lists based on the difference between adjacent elements?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

E.g., if I've got

```
MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF = 3
nums=[1, 2, 4, 10, 13, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

the output should be

```
groups = [[1, 2, 4], [10, 13], [2, 5, 5, 5]]
```

The context: I had a `pandas.Series object nums` and I used

```
nums = nums.diff().gt(DETECTION_MAX_DIFF_NS).cumsum()).apply(list).tolist()
```

to subsample in the same fashion but I noticed that there're a lot of duplicates in my `Series nums` and after I use `.unique()` method I don't have `Series` object anymore, I've got `numpy.ndarray` (1D) instead.

I believe I may use sth like `pandas.Series(nums.unique)` but I don't like this hack.

Comment: So the solution is for a list or a Series?

Comment: @yatu the former which is np.array (because that's what I receive after `Series.unique()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we using `drop_duplicates`, keep `nums` stay in `pd.Series`

```
nums=nums.drop_duplicates()
nums.groupby(nums.diff().abs().gt(MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF).cumsum()).apply(list).tolist()
Out[447]: [[1, 2, 4], [10, 13], [5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach -

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> idx = np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.abs(np.diff(nums))>MAX_ALLOWED_DIFF)+1,len(nums)]
>>> [nums[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(idx[:-1],idx[1:])]
[[1, 2, 4], [10, 13], [2, 5, 5, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that you've tagged with `numpy` too, here's one way to do it:

```
thr = 3
ix = np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate([[False], np.abs(np.diff(nums))>thr]))
np.split(nums, ix)
```

**Output**

```
[array([1, 2, 4]), array([10, 13]), array([2, 5, 5, 5])]
```